# Powershell: Missing DLL files when running in a 32-bit mode

Tags: powershell

In order to get the DLL files running under a certain process I am using the following line of code:

`$Modules += Get-Process -Id $ProcessId | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Modules`

This line of code works perfectly fine when running in a 64-bit mode. However, when using a 32-bit mode I have noticed that the same process returns **less** modules than in a 64-bit mode.

Why is this happening ? and since i need to run my script in a 32-bit mode, is there any other method of getting the requested DLL files ?

Comment: The dlls have to support both architectures. If they don't have 32bit version of the dll then it won't be usable.

Comment: So how could it be that it returns less modules in 32-bit ?

Comment: Because you have DLLs that are for 64bit and cant be recognized by a 32bit pull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments on the question, **32-bit processes cannot access modules of 64-bit processes**, so you cannot use your command as-is from 32-bit PowerShell if the target process is a 64-bit process.

In fact, if you try to access a 64-bit Windows PowerShell instance from a 32-bit one with your command, you get an explicit error message to that effect, at least on Windows 10 with Windows PowerShell v5.1:

```
A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.
```

---

As a **suboptimal workaround**, you can **invoke 64-bit Windows PowerShell via its CLI (`powershell.exe`) from your 32-bit instance**:

```
$ps64 = "$($PSHOME -replace '\\SysWOW64\\', '\\SysNative\\')\powershell.exe" 
& $ps64 -noprofile { (Get-Process -Id 1468 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Modules) }
```

The workaround is suboptimal in two respects:

- It involves creation of a new PowerShell instance in a new process, which is slow.
- More importantly, the objects that are returned are only *approximations* of the `System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule` instances that direct invocation would return.

  - Specifically, they are `[pscustomobject]` instances - with a type name of `Deserialized.System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule` to indicate their source - that have properties of the same names as the original objects, with static copies of their values (which may themselves be such `[pscustomobject]` instances; also, these instances lack the *methods* that the original objects have.
  - That said, if all you need is to access properties such as `.ModuleName` or `.FileName`, you shouldn't have a problem.